Make extra arrow bends in database diagramming (ERD) tool in SQL Server Management Studio?
I'm using the database diagramming tool in SSMS. It readily allows up to 2 bends on the relationship arrows. But sometimes I need 3 or more bends. Does anyone know a way to achieve this? The following example has been photoshopped (fudged) to illustrate a sample goal. I realize other products do such, but our shop convention is SSMS for ERD's.
Thank you!


If you drag the line part for the ∞ (with the smallest red arrow next to it) upwards and then past the top of its table, the line will become attached to the top end of the table and create an extra bend.
This can be repeated by moving the new line part past other corners. And it works for all connecting line ends.
It can be a bit awkward to have to do it like this, but AFAIK there is no other way.

In SSMS, the diagramming tool does not allow more than 2 bends directly in relationship lines.
If you want, you can try other tools, such as MySQL Workbench, dbdiagram.io, DBeaver, etc., for advanced diagram customization.
